# How to change the label name in Risc v

Tags: assembly, riscv

Im writing a program in RISC V assembly to ask the user for his name as per the dialogue
What is your name?
Lena
Hello Lena!

This is what I have but I keep getting this error.

I don't know the exact problem I tried changing the label name but still

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcYKT.png)

Comment: `_` isn't a letter.  The error message from that simulator you're using says your label has to start with a letter, and can only contain letters and numbers.  So `_start` won't work in that simulator.  Change it to something else, like `start:`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with what @PeterCordes said and try beginning it like this:

```
section .data
   # put your data here
section .text
.globl start
start:
   # put your code here
```

Unfortunately, unlike C, assemblers are *not standardized*. Different assemblers have different syntax, and some will accept naming conventions that others will not. What you wrote may work perfectly fine on a different assembler but not this one. Even the comment character may vary (most assemblers regardless of language use a semicolon but this is not always the case.) I used the `#` sign which MARS/RARS use, but that might not even be correct for your assembler!